# Split Array Cells in Java

Tags: java, c

outp is of unsigned short* type. Some manipulations need to be done depending on the mode where **mode is a global variable**. In the if-block val is assigned to outp at the calculated index. In if-else block first the address pointed by outc is calculated and then the value is assigned at that location **which in turn leads to change in a paricular cell of outp**.

```
void lds_ld(int val, int x, int y, int value, unsigned short* outp)
{
    unsigned char *outc;
    if(mode==1)
    {
           outp[y*width +x] = val;
    }
    else if (mode==2)
    {
           outc = (unsigned char *)outp +y*width + x;
           *outc= value;
    }
    else
    {
           printf("Wrong mode");
    }
}
```

I need to write a java code that performs the same function. So i have written:

```
void lds_ld(int val, int x, int y, int value, int outp[])
{
    short outc[];
    if(mode==1)
    {
           outp[y*width +x] = val;
    }
    else if (mode==2)
    {
           //what to write here
    }
    else
    {
           System.out.printf("Wrong mode");
    }
}
```

To write the if-else block i some how need to first split each array cell into two and then calculate the index and assign value at that index and then convert this array back to int[] type. whole  How can i do this?

Comment: Where does `mode` come from? It's not a parameter ... - Additionally, how would you access `outc` outside the method? What about just returning it from the method (at least in the java version)?

Comment: i don't need to access outc. outc is in providing a way to edit outp

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case I'd say you don't need mode 2 in Java, since that would be essentially the same as mode 1 (as AlexR already pointed out, there are no pointers in Java).

Comment: @Thomas Both modes are different. if it is mode 1 then i have to edit the complete cell of outp and if it is mode 2 i need to edit only the half cell of outp

Comment: So how would you edit the second half of the cell if you'd need to? Also, what is _value_ as opposed to _val_? This method seems quite odd to me.

Comment: I need to first split the array outp into an array with each cell having half the size and total length twice the length of outp and then again combine the cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mode 2 seems to allow you to only edit the first byte of the short, so you might try this:

```
int arrayValue = outp[y * width + x];
int firstByte = (arrayValue >> 8) & 0xFF;
int secondByte = arrayValue & 0xFF;

firstByte = value;
//if you want to edit the second byte:
//secondByte = value;

outp[y * width + x] = (int)(firstByte << 8) + secondByte;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 16 instead of 8 here??

Comment: @RogMatthews No, the last 2 bytes of the integer would contain the unsigned short value, i.e. unsigned short 0xABCD would be integer 0x0000ABCD. Thus you need to use 8 here, 16 would result in 0x00000000 instead of 0x000000AB.

Comment: Nice point. One more thing, In firstByte isn't & unnecassary?

Comment: @RogMatthews It's a safeguard here since to ensure that if the first two bytes of the integer were not 0 they' not matter. Since you actually change the value of `firstByte` the entire line would'nt be necessary (unless you want to change the second byte of the short only). Please also note that for safety reasons, you might also use `firstByte = value 0xFF;` in case `value` accidentially was < 0 or > 255.

Comment: @RogMatthews My bad, was meant to be `firstByte = value & 0xFF`. Unfortunately, I can't edit the comment anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There are no pointers in java, so you can either work on the same array and remember index to start from or create new array and copy part of source array to the target:

```
// check array size calculations: I am not sure I completely 
// your logic but I am sure you do.
int outc = new int[outp - (y*width + x)]; understand 
System.arraycopy(outp, y*width + x, outc, 0, outc.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how `width` is set, you are

1) either setting two shorts from an int

2) or you are setting one half of a short, another short, and another half of a short from the int. Which halves of the shorts you are changing (most or least significant) will depend on your CPU architecture (and maybe your compiler)

Since (2) is quite painful, let's assume (1), i.e. width % 2 == 0. In Java, you have to split the int for yourself instead of assuming casting magic:

```
 // determine the least significant 16 bits of your int
short lower = (short)(value & 0xffff);
 // determine the most significant 16 bits of your int
short upper = (short)(value >>> 16);
// same calculation as in C-code, but for a short-array instead of for char-array
int pos = (y * width + x) / 2;
// assuming little endian order in your array (similar to running the C-code on x86
outp[pos] = lower;
outp[pos + 1] = upper;
```

For option (2) you need to split your int into three values:

```
byte left = (byte)(value & 0xff);
short middle = (short)(value >>> 8);
byte right = (byte)(value >> 24);
```

After doing so, you can assign `middle` directly to `outp[pos]`, but you must combine the left and right bytes with the existing values in the cell using bit-manipulation-operations:

```
if ((y * width + x) % 2) != 0) {
  // still assuming little endianness
  outp[pos - 1] = (short)(outp[pos - 1] & 0xff00 | left);
  outp[pos + 1] = (short)(((right << 8) & 0xff00) | (outp[pos + 1] & 0xff));
}
```

Comment: Actually i need to do the (2) option and then put it back as int to outp

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing the given task would be using [java.nio.ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) classes:

```
import java.nio.*;
// Wrap outp into a ByteBuffer

ByteBuffer outpBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(outp);
outpBuf.putInt(y * width + x, value);
```

Please note that ByteBuffer is initially using Big Endian ordering, so you need to use `outpBuf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)` to get results equivalent to the direct bit-operations suggested by the other posters.